# Configuring websvn Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

I need to create a server `websvn` for my programs.

I did install websvn in the server and work but showed me this message.

```
Please set up a repository in include/config.php using $config->parentPath or $config->addRepository. See the installation guide for more details.
```

So I did a nano include/config.php

```
    <?php
$config->parentPath("/var/lib/svn");
$config->addRepository("FirstRepo", "file:///var/lib/svn/FirstRepo");
$config->setEnscriptPath("/usr/bin");
$config->setSedPath("/bin");
$config->useEnscript();
    ?>
```

Then a `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now If I go the URL `http://192.168.x.xxx/websvn/` the site goes blank and the view get loss

Here is the route where I have my repos `/var/lib/svn` and inside of that I have to folder `FirstRepo`

Do not know if I did something wrong or not.

`apt list php-xml`

```
Listing... Done
php-xml/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1 all
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

`ls -la /var/lib/svn/FirstRepo`

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 root     root 4096 Aug 20 10:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data root 4096 Aug 20 10:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     root 4096 Aug 20 10:52 conf
drwxrwsr-x 6 root     root 4096 Aug 20 10:52 db
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root     root    2 Aug 20 10:52 format
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     root 4096 Aug 20 10:52 hooks
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     root 4096 Aug 20 10:52 locks
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root     root  246 Aug 20 10:52 README.txt
```

Comment: Could you post output of the commands: `apt list php-xml`and `ls -la /var/lib/svn/FirstRepo`

Comment: @Bob Done add in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `php-xml` package:

```
sudo apt install php-xml
```

Restart apache afterwards and check if everything is OK.